# RegExp for Numbers in the Thousands

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I'm trying to grab post counts from a users on a forum.

```
if (td[i].innerHTML.match("Posts: (\d+)")) {
  postCount = RegExp.$1;
}
```

It works, but if a number is in the thousands, it only grabs the first number. How can this be adjusted to grab the entire number such as 1,000?

Comment: Is localization an issue, or will the values always be formatted using commas as the thousands separator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen this way of using regular expressions. But this should do it:

```
/Posts: (\d+(?:,\d+)?)/
```

This wouldn't match `1,000,000` though, if you want to cover all cases, change `?` to `*`:

```
/Posts: (\d+(?:,\d+)*)/
```

Answer (score 1):

More grist for the mill... if you want to test for numbers with thousands seperators excatly, you can do something like:

```
var matches = td[i].innerHTML.match(/\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*/);
postCount = matches? matches[0] : 0;
```

It may be better to use textContent/innerText than innerHTML since you might want to remove markup. A simple function can be:

```
function getText(el) {

  if (typeof el.textContent == 'string') {
    return el.textContent;

  } else if (typeof el.innerText == 'string') {
    return el.innerText;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Posts: (\d*,?\d+)
```

**Edit:** If you want to match 1,000,000 (like Felix Kling demonstrates), you need a repeating capturing group for the upper part:

```
Posts: ((?:\d+,)*\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are using a comma number format such as 1,000,000,000 then the following regex should work nicely:

```
$posts = "Posts: 10,000,000";
$pat = "/Posts: (\d+(?:,\d{3})*)/";
preg_match($pat, $posts, $matches);
$post_count = $matches[1];
```

Comment: I think that second '+' should be a '*'.  You want to be able to match "Posts: 123" as well.

Comment: Good catch, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the commas, just change your pattern to:

```
Posts: (\d+(,\d{3})*)
```

If you don't want the commas, you'll need an extra step. Someone help me out with the JS syntax, but I suppose it might be:

```
postCount = RegExp.$1.replace(/,/g, '')
```

Comment: Your regex is missing a closing `)`

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Stupid copy/paste error on my part.