# Get Silver or Gold Rate

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm written widget program to get price of silver or gold price from Bloomberg website
these are parts of the script :

```
function getPrice()  {

    var url = new URL();
    url.location = "http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/commodities/futures/";
    url.fetchAsync(PriceReturn);
}


function PriceReturn(url)   {

    var resultStr = url.result;     
    var subCheck = resultStr.substring(resultStr.indexOf("SILVER"));    
    foundStr = subCheck.match("[0-9]+\.[0-9]+");
    setPrice(parseFloat(foundStr).toFixed(2));
}
```

I can get the price for Silver (let say now 27.30) but when I want to check for Gold Price (`.indexOf("GOLD")`) (let say right now 1,585.60)

What is the `subcheck.match()` script to get that price?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegExp for Numbers in the Thousands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044278/regexp-for-numbers-in-the-thousands)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` doesn't match number like `1,585.60`. Correct regular expression is:

```
/\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2}/
```

This matches formatted numbers to two decimal places.

Comment: @VamanKulkarni I think this just happens in C#, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ww5GU/1/)

Comment: thanks, but i didn't work it return to null, any help i will appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I think te pattern should be like this:

```
/\d+(\,\d+)?\.\d{1,3}/
```

Comment: with this patter, I'M still just getting "585.60" instead of "1,585.60"

Comment: the pattern still cannot recognize "comma"

Comment: What do you mean? You can add ?:, so the group will be non-caputring, so the pattern looks like this: /\d+(?:\,\d+)?\.\d{1,3}/, and then foundStr should be an array ["1,585.60"].